# How to parse and serialize an Abstract User in another model?

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to create a `APIView` for a *post* request that saves an image and retrieves the user value in the request to fill one of the fields of the model. However, I've been stuck as all I've been getting here was `PlotImage has no user.`

How do I pass the current user model in the request to a serializer ?

Models.py

```py
class AppUser(AbstractUser):
   email = models.EmailField(...)
   ....

class ImageModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(...)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AppUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mix_id = models.IntegerField()
    plot_id = models.IntegerField()
```

Serializer.py

```py
def PlotImagesInputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
     model = ImageModel
     fields = ('plot_id','image','mix_id')
```

view.py

```
class MixImagesCreateView(APIView):
    parser_classes =  [MultiPartParser, FormParser]
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PlotImagesInputSerializer(data=request.FILES, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the requested user in ImageModel inside your post method in view.py

Try as follows:

```
serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Full code

```
class MixImagesCreateView(APIView):
    parser_classes =  [MultiPartParser, FormParser]
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PlotImagesInputSerializer(data=request.FILES, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```